# When to load its views when a UIViewController created in another Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know what happened between step one and step two.

Will subController layout its views automatically?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    SubViewController *ctl = [[SubViewController alloc] init];//step one
    [self.view addSubView:ctl.view]; //step two
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on in your "step 2". First, calling ctl.view will result in the view being loaded by whatever means determined by the controller. Second, when it is added as a subview, the parent view will tell the `ctl.view` to layout its view.